# Animation of UIImage initiated by button

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton, uiimage

I wish to animate a 50x50 UIImage across the screen like an ECG blip at the touch of a button.

I am using a test project and have this working without a button:

```
@interface IPhoneViewController ()

@end

@implementation IPhoneViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}


 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0F animations:^{
    CGPoint oldPosition = self.dot.layer.position;
    CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(oldPosition.x + 170, oldPosition.y);
    self.dot.layer.position = newPosition;


    }];

 }



@end
```

When I add the line `- (IBAction)onButtonPressed:(id)sender; {` just above this code, an error is created at the line `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {` stating "Use of undeclared identifier 'viewDidAppear'".

Firstly, how can I start the animation with the button and secondly, I would like to alter the direction of the animation in an up and down motion like ECG machines do, but if I add another set of directions after the first, only the last instructions are implemented.

```
 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0F animations:^{
    CGPoint oldPosition = self.dot.layer.position;
    CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(oldPosition.x + 170, oldPosition.y);
    self.dot.layer.position = newPosition;


}];
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0F animations:^{
     CGPoint oldPosition = self.dot.layer.position;
     CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(oldPosition.x + 10, oldPosition.y - 100);
     self.dot.layer.position = newPosition;


 }];

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
- (IBAction)onButtonPressed:(id)sender{
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0F animations:^{
    CGPoint oldPosition = self.dot.layer.position;
    CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(oldPosition.x + 170, oldPosition.y);
    self.dot.layer.position = newPosition;


}completion:^(BOOL finished){
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0F animations:^{
    CGPoint oldPosition = self.dot.layer.position;
    CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(oldPosition.x + 10, oldPosition.y - 100);
    self.dot.layer.position = newPosition;


}];
}];


}
```

This should work, and your animations should be one after the other.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The button works fine but I get an error message at    }completion:^{

Comment: Thanks for responding. The button works fine, but I get an error message at    `}completion:^{`   indicating ^  stating " Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void'(^)(void) to parameter of type 'void (^)(bool)'. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm so sorry, it was an error in my code. I have edited it, and now it should work. Let me know if it does. :D

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly. I've integrated it into my app and I'm very pleased with the result. I am very grateful indeed. I wish you well in your projects.

Comment: If it answered your question, please accept and upvote the answer, thanks. Happy to help!